# Streaming data in Julia

Tags: julia

Currently, is there a good way to read data in Julia in a streaming fashion?

For example, let's say I have a CSV file that is too big to fit in memory. Are there currently built in functions or a library that facilitates working with this?

I'm aware of the prototype DataStream functionality in DataFrames, but that's not currently exposed via a public API.

Comment: Unfortunately, the best approach would be to clean up the DataStream code. It's surprisingly close to finished, but it would take about a day's worth of work to get ready for use.

Answer (score 3):

The eachline function turns an IO source into an iterator of lines. That should allow you to read a file a line at a time. from there the readcsv and readdlm function can read each line if you turn it into an IOBuffer.

```
for ln in eachline(open("file.csv"))
  data = readcsv(IOBuffer(ln))
  # do something with this data
end
```

It's still pretty do it yourself but there aren't that many steps so it's not too bad.